# Envíar 2 parametros a un controlador laravel

Tags: laravel, rutas

Tengo una vista con 2 `foreach`, quiero llevarme al controlador 2 parámetros, uno de cada `foreach`.

No sé como llevarme los 2 parámetros mediante `href` o no se si se pueda de otra forma.

Código:

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-striped  table-bordered">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <thead>
                    <th class="table-warning">Maestro</th>
                    <th class="table-warning">ID grado y grupo</th>
                    <th class="table-warning">Clave</th>
                    <th class="table-warning">Grupo</th>
                    <th class="table-warning">Calificar</th>
                </thead>
            @foreach ($c_grado_c_grupo as $c_grad_c_grup)

                    <tr class="table-warning"> 
                        <td>{{$c_grad_c_grup->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$c_grad_c_grup->fk_grado_grupo}}</td>
                        <td>{{$c_grad_c_grup->grado_nombre}}</td>
                        <td>{{$c_grad_c_grup->grupo_clave}}</td>
                        <td>

            <table class="table table-striped  table-bordered">
                <div class="row">
                        <thead>
                            <th class="table-warning">ID</th>
                            <th class="table-warning">Materia</th>
                            <th class="table-warning">Calificar</th>


                        </thead>

                            @foreach ($materiasxmaestro as $materiasxma)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$materiasxma->idc_materia}}</td>
                                <td>{{$materiasxma->mat_nombre}}</td>

                                <td><a href="{{ route('k_calificacion.asignar',$materiasxma->idc_materia)}} {{route('k_calificacion.asignar', $c_grad_c_grup->fk_grado_grupo)}}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Calificar</a>

                            </tr>
                            @endforeach

                            </div>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>

               @endforeach


             </div> 
        </div> 
    </div>
</table>

 <center> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="/_usuario_grado">
<i class="fa fa fa-reply" ></i> Regresar</button> </center>
<br>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
</div>
<footer>
@include('admin.template.partials.footer')
@yield('')
</footer>
@endsection


`
```

y mi ruta es

```
Route::get('k_calificacion/{id}/{idk}/asignar', [
            'uses' => 'K_calificacionController@asignar',
            'as'=>'k_calificacion.asignar']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí es posible , en el `href` podría seguir empleando el helper [route('nameruta',[params])](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-route) con el cambio que los parámetros los pase como un `array` *clave,valor*  o solo los valores. *(el formato es para evitar el scroll)*

```
<a href="{{ route('k_calificacion.asignar',
           ['id'=> $materiasxma->idc_materia , 
            'idk'=>$c_grad_c_grup->fk_grado_grupo])}} "
class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Calificar</a>
```

O

```
<a href="{{ route('k_calificacion.asignar',
              [ $materiasxma->idc_materia , $c_grad_c_grup->fk_grado_grupo])}} "
class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Calificar</a>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me has ayudado bastante, ya tenía muchas horas buscando.!